# Product Layout messed up when stting a product to oos in Jm siotis theme in magento

Tags: php, magento, layout

The link to the issue is http://www.nerd-vault.com/clothing.html which uses the JM Siotis theme in magento. The issue is when I set a product to out of stock, the product layout gets messed up and there are gaps in my catalog.

Is there an easy fix to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing an issue because all the out-of-stock products are right at the bottom, but I think I know what you're experiencing when you set other products to out-of-stock.

The "Out of Stock" text changes the height of the items in the `product-grid` ul. Try setting a min-height on your grid items.

```
.products-grid .item {
  min-height: 350px
}
```

Comment: Yep, you need to set a responsible height for the grid, it is a -grid- after all!